# Tables with a lot of data for small screen sizes

Tags: usability, gui-design, layout, responsive-design, data-tables

It is probably not just me who finds responsive tables barely readable when using small screen devices. In most of cases they look like in example #1.

I find this way completely impractical when presenting a lot of data as it involves a lot of vertical scrolling and is often confusing.

Surely tables as in example #2 do not fit a lot of data, which becomes impractical too unless you only require a couple of columns with short input.

I wonder if anyone managed to achieve a table presentation that would provide good readability on small screen size devices?

**Example #1**

[image]

**Example #2**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to use horizontal scrolling. In my opinion this is the most convenient way to display large data sets. However, make sure to prominently indicate the possibility of scrolling horizontally. Nielsen recently published an article on mobile tables with some useful hints on how to cope with mobile tables: https://www.nngroup.com/articles/mobile-tables/